# How can I fix an image link that's not working?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I am trying to get an image for the navbar of my page to link back to my site's homepage. I have tried using the code below, but for some reason only the top of the image is clickable. I have inspected it and tried for ages but I cannot find anything that looks out of place or has incorrect syntax.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

```css
nav {
  height: 85px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav img {
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: var(--primary) !important;
  transition: 0.15s;
}

nav img {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav .responsive-nav {
  display: none;
}

nav .right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 27px;
  right: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  height: 85px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav .right ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 27px;
  right: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

nav .right li {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

nav .right a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

nav h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.15s;
}

nav h1 a:hover {
  color: var(--primary);
  transition: 0.15s;
}

nav .menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid var(--primary);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: var(--primary);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="/"><img src="https://www.gsr-technology.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/partner-logo-placeholder.jpg" /></a>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars menu"></i>
  </nav>
```

Comment: why are you using position:fixed ? the `.right` div is overlapping the logo (add a background color to better see the issue)

Comment: What do your browser developer tools reveal when you inspect the markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In above code `nav .right` and `nav .right ul` both have width: 100%; remove that and try it will done and whole image will be clickable.

Comment: Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: @B.Sommer This solution solves the problem with the code you've posted. If you are still having the issue then you need to update the question with all the code you actually have. However, the preferable solution is for you to extrapolate on what this fix entails and then apply it to your real scenario wherever there is a code conflict (e.g.) overlapping.

Comment: I tried removing both the lines with 'width: 100%;' in. Is this correct?

Comment: I realised my error: I had changed the styles in my css file but rules later down in a media query was overwriting that.